# Does Gmail deal with contacts email changing?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

People change jobs or change email. So we need to update their contact details in Gmail. Does Gmail keep track of the old email addresses behind the scenes?

I have always kept the old email addresses in contacts so that when I want to show "recent conversations" I get a full history. This works, but it also means I need to make sure I don't select an old address when emailing them in future.

Answer (score 9):

No Gmail will make a duplicate contact out of it, which you will have to merge 'manually'.

Luckily [this is a very easy process](http://www.googletutor.com/how-to-merge-all-duplicate-gmail-contacts-with-one-click/), though it may take some time if you don't keep up with it.

Gmail even [helps you find duplicates](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/one-button-to-merge-all-duplicate.html) if their name doesn't change much. Else you just have to select them both and click [Merge]

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/SygT6ZJoPdI/AAAAAAAAAbk/8oVtYVzoJBM/mergecontacts1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/SyfHaVoFKdI/AAAAAAAAAbU/rW23cBCerKs/mergecontacts2.png))</sub>

Comment: Useful info, and something that I wasn't aware of.
But that can leave me with a contact with 10 email addresses, only two of which are "live" and all of which get presented as possible addresses when composing new.